# Index mapping for elasticsearch is not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm not able to do mapping for my data with the below mapping. In elasticsearch index "integerinput" field is shown as "text".
Below are the part of json template file and logstash config file

template.json

```
{
        "mappings":{
                "_doc":{
                        "properties":{
                                "textinput":{
                                        "type":"text"
                                },
                                "name":{
                                        "type":"text"
                                },
                                "integerinput":{
                                        "type":"integer"
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

logstash-config file:

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        ssl => true
        manage_template => true
        user => 'elastic'
        password => '******'
        hosts => "https://elasticip:port"
        cacert => '/path to certificate file'
        index => "template-mapping-index"
        template => "/path to template/template.json"
}
}
```

can anyone help me where i made misatake

Comment: whats the query you are getting ? and you are getting an error while creating and index or while indinxg a document ?

Comment: Maybe you have already a mapping in your index because of formerly inserted docs? In this case elastic  will guess the datatype and you cannot change the mapping without reindexing

Comment: @irathod I'm not getting any errors. Documents are getting inserted. But "integerinput" field i want to insert as integer but it is inserted as text. mapping which i passed is not applied to the document on insertion.

Comment: @ ibexit this happens with new index only.